# How to add Tasks as a backlog navigation level in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Asking this here rather than softwareengineering, simply because there is a tag for VSTS here while there isn't one there...

So currently I'm seeing this:

[image]

What I'd like to see is 'Tasks' in there alongside Epics, Features, and Stories, and have it mapped to the 'Tasks' WIT.

How do I do this?

I've had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=vsts, but I'm not sure if that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be achieved with the standard Task work item. The Task Level is a special kind of level which enables the Task Board and iterations. The distinction of pretty artificial and it stems from the time when TFS didn't event have a Feature or Epic level and there were just two kinds of plans: Longterm (story, pbi, requirement) or short term (tasks).